# inner join with php the browser display a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a select query with inner join. I try it in phpmyadmin it works fine. But when I try it in the browser it display this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT s.specialization_name FROM user u INNER JO' at line 1

**member_search.php**

```
/default  message  on top of the result  display
$querySrting="WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date ASC ";
$queryMSG="Showing newest to oldest memebrs by default";
///IF STATMENT TO DISTINGOUICH SEARCHING
if(isset($_POST['listbyq']))
{
  if($_POST['listbyq']=="newest_members")
  {
      $querySrting="WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date DESC " or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="Showing senior to oldest memebrs";
  }
elseif($_POST['listbyq']=="by_specialization")

   {
      $querySrting="SELECT specialization_name FROM members u 
                         INNER JOIN specialization s 
                                     ON u.specialization=s.specialization_id";

    $result = mysql_query($querySrting)  or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="showing members with specs";
   }
elseif($_POST['listbyq']=="by_firstname")
  {
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $fname = stripcslashes($fname);
      $fname = strip_tags($fname);
      $querySrting="WHERE  first_name LIKE '%$fname%'"or die(mysql_error());
      $queryMSG="Showing member with the name you searched for";
  }
}
///******query the member data using the queryString*******//
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, specialization, registered_date FROM members $querySrting") or die(mysql_error());
 //**********************outputlist*********************************//
 $outputlist="";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
     $id=$row['user_id'];
     $firstname=$row['first_name'];
     $lastname=$row['last_name'];
     $birthdate=$row['birth_date'];
     $spec = $row['specialization'];
     $registereddate=$row['registered_date']; 
     ////***********for the upload image*************************//
      $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
   }

   $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$id.'" target="_blank">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$registereddate.'</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">His Job:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$spec.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';

 }//close while
```

Comment: You have an SQL syntax error. Showing us a wall of PHP code is pointless. show us the actual query that caused the syntax error.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

`$querySrting` is a variable. You should concatenate those strings:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,
                           first_name,
                           last_name,
                           birth_date,
                           specialization,
                           registered_date
                    FROM members $querySrting") // HERE
```

Should be like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,
                           first_name,
                           last_name,
                           birth_date,
                           specialization,
                           registered_date
                    FROM members".$querySrting) // HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is outright attrocious and shows major symptoms of cargo-cult programming:

```
  $querySrting="WHERE  first_name LIKE '%$fname%'"or die(mysql_error());
```

You're assigning a bit of text to a variable, which cannot possibly fail, yet you try to treat it as a potential SQL error. You're not EXECUTE that small snippet of SQL, so there is absolutely **NO** way an sql error could be triggered by this line.

Immediately before the previous line, you have

```
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $fname = stripcslashes($fname);
  $fname = strip_tags($fname);
```

which leaves you WIDE OPEN for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). By running $fname through stripcslashes(), you've removed the one MINOR utterly **FAINT HOPE** of preventing an injection attack, assuming you're on a PHP that has magic_quotes enabled.

On top of this, none of the queries you have in your code are the actual query causing the SQL error you're getting. The error clearly states **FROM USER u**, which does not appear anywhere in your code.